# Question on [over.match.funcs.general]/9 and inherited copy/move constructors

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, overload-resolution, using-declaration

Per [§ 12.2.2.1 [over.match.funcs.general]/9-sentence-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-9.sentence-2):

> A constructor inherited from class type C ([class.inhctor.init]) that
> has a first parameter of type “reference to cv1 P” (including such a
> constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of
> candidate functions when constructing an object of type cv2 D if the
> argument list has exactly one argument and C is reference-related to P
> and P is reference-related to D.

I am just trying to understand this paragraph and somehow conduct an example that matches the wording then I want to apply that example to the paragraph:

```
struct P;
struct C { C(); C(const P&); };
struct P : C { using C::C; };
struct D : P {}; 

D d{ P() };
```

From the above example: `C` is reference-related to `P` and `P` is reference-related to `D`. And there's a constructor inherited from class type `C` that has a first parameter of type “reference to `cv1 P`”. And when constructing an object of type `cv D` -and the argument list has exactly one argument which is `P()`- then this inherited constructor is excluded from the set of candidate functions.

Does my example match what the wording intends? And Do I understand and parse the wording correctly? Also, Is there any other wording regarding this point (inheriting copy/move constructors)?

Comment: I misread the question. I though you were getting an error. I think you should tag a language version for a focused answer. (that would be better then some of the tags your are now using)

Answer (score 2):

This example has nothing to do with inheriting constructors: it works even with either or both of `C(const P&);` and `using C::C;` removed.  It’s doing **aggregate** initialization of a `D` by supplying a value for its one subobject (the base `P`).

Note that there is no “compiler-generated `D::D(const P&)`”, although the effect is similar to what one might expect it to do.  In C++17, changing to `D d((P()));` fails, but C++20 lets that be aggregate initialization too.

Comment: Is my example matching the wording of the standard I provide? This is basically what I am asking for. if not, please provide an example matching the wording

Comment: @SofaJoe: Your question asks “Does my example match what the wording intends?”, and I already said it illustrates a completely different thing about aggregate initialization.  The standard already has an example for that paragraph, so I’m not sure what else you want.